# Creating Group via Microsoft Graph returns Error "An unexpected PrimitiveValue node was found when reading from the JSON reader"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Am trying to create `group` using my admin account via Microsoft Graph. I have implemented all the required parameters/variables but when I tried making calls to the API, it displays error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "02bfcc43-5982-4c49-8484-da9d6cc61bab",
            "date": "2017-12-05T17:53:57"
        }
    }
}
```

My code:

```php
<?php 
session_start();


echo $acc= $_SESSION['access_token'];

$data_string = array("description" => "An Awesome New Group", "displayName" => "Awesome Group", "groupTypes" => "Unified", "mailEnabled" => "true", "mailNickname" => "awesomeGroup", "securityEnabled" => "fasle"); 
$data = json_encode($data_string); 
//$data = $data_string; 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups",

CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: Bearer $acc", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);



print_r($response);




if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
//echo $response; 
}
?>
```

Note that my real tenant id was replaced with `admin@secx34fake.onmicrosoft.com` so that its not displayed to public.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the URL you're using is invalid.

This is accurate as `/v1.0/admin@secx34fake.onmicrosoft.com/groups` isn't a valid endpoint. Specifically it rejecting the `userPrincipalName` of  `admin@secx34fake.onmicrosoft.com`. I'm not exactly sure where you were going with this but a `Group` is not a child of a `User` object. A User can be a member of a Group but they are both top-level elements within your Active Directory.

> As an aside, a "segment" in the context of a URL is the elements separated by a `/`. You can think of a URL as a `/` delimited string with each column being a "segment". For example, `/v1.0/me/events` contains 3 segments: `v1.0`, `me` and `events`. The error you got is telling you one of these "segments" is either invalid or not in the proper order (i.e. `/v1.0/events/me` has the right segments in the wrong order).

For [creating a Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups), the proper URI looks like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

Within the body of your `POST` you define the properties of the group. For example:

```json
{
  "description": "An Awesome New Group",
  "displayName": "Awesome Group",
  "groupTypes": ["Unified"],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "awesomeGroup",
  "securityEnabled": false
}
```

Comment: At Marc,Thanks for your help so far, I have updated my question/Post to reflect your suggested solutions but when i run the code, it shows error **An unexpected PrimitiveValue node was found when reading from the JSON reader, A StartArray node was expected**. Please can you help me further

Comment: What does the encoded `$data` value look like? This error is telling you there is a problem with the JSON you're sending over.

Comment: I still cannot resolve it.  how will this kind of data be sent **["Unified"]**. similar problems has been posted and resolve here but i dont understand how it was done **https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/66a54e38-702c-4435-b59a-03abd5947513/while-trying-to-create-a-search-index-using-phpcurl-i-keep-getting-the-response-the-request-is?forum=azuresearch**

Comment: `groupTypes` is an array: `"property": ["value1", "value2", etc]`.